# Replace '-' with space if the next charcter is a letter not a digit and remove when it is at the start

Tags: regex, python-3.x, string

I have a list of string i.e.

```
slist = ["-args", "-111111", "20-args", "20 - 20", "20-10", "args-deep"]
```

I want to remove the '-' from string where **it is the first character and is followed by strings but not numbers** or if **before the '-' there is number/alphabet but after it is alphabets, then it should replace the '-' with space**

So for the list **slist** I want the output as

```
["args", "-111111", "20 args", "20 - 20", "20-10", "args deep"]
```

I have tried

```
slist = ["-args", "-111111", "20-args", "20 - 20", "20-10", "args-deep"]
nlist = list()
for estr in slist:
    nlist.append(re.sub("((^-[a-zA-Z])|([0-9]*-[a-zA-Z]))", "", estr))
print (nlist)
```

and i get the output

```
['rgs', '-111111', 'rgs', '20 - 20', '20-10', 'argseep']
```

Comment: Try `nlist.append(re.sub(r"-(?=[a-zA-Z])", " ", estr).strip())`. I do not think that the *where it is the first character* is an actual requirement judging by the expected output.

Comment: Note that "alphabet" is Indian English. The generic English term is "letter".

Comment: Arghya, did you have time to check my approach?

Comment: thanks to all for the answers
@WiktorStribiżew i just need to replace the character with space if it is not the first character , so if it is the first character, then strip removes that, so ya it is not an actual requirement

Comment: Ok, so I amended the title and posted [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56316774/3832970) with explanations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
nlist.append(re.sub(r"-(?=[a-zA-Z])", " ", estr).lstrip())
```

or

```
nlist.append(re.sub(r"-(?=[^\W\d_])", " ", estr).lstrip())
```

Result: `['args', '-111111', '20 args', '20 - 20', '20-10', 'args deep']`

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VtJm3S).

The `-(?=[a-zA-Z])` pattern matches a hyphen before an ASCII letter (`-(?=[^\W\d_])` matches a hyphen before any letter), and replaces the match with a space. Since `-` may be matched at the start of a string, the space may appear at that position, so `.lstrip()` is used to remove the space(s) there.

Answer (score 1):

Here, we might just want to capture the first letter after a starting `-`, then replace it with that letter only, maybe with an `i` flag expression similar to:

```
^-([a-z])
```

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/hgO4XM/1/)

[image]

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^-([a-z])"

test_str = ("-args\n"
    "-111111\n"
    "20-args\n"
    "20 - 20\n"
    "20-10\n"
    "args-deep")

subst = "\\1"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Demo

```js
const regex = /^-([a-z])/gmi;
const str = `-args
-111111
20-args
20 - 20
20-10
args-deep`;
const subst = `$1`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### RegEx

If this expression wasn't desired, it can be modified or changed in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/hgO4XM/1/).

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to do 2 times a replacement. First match the hyphen at the start when there are only  alphabets following:

```
^-(?=[a-zA-Z]+$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jAcDy5/1)

In the replacement use an empty string.

Then capture 1 or more times an alphabet or digit in group 1, match `-` followed by capturing 1+ times an alphabet in group 2.

```
^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sKY46x/1)

In the replacement use `r"\1 \2"`

For example

```
import re

regex1 = r"^-(?=[a-zA-Z]+$)"
regex2 = r"^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)$"

slist = ["-args", "-111111", "20-args", "20 - 20", "20-10", "args-deep"]
slist = list(map(lambda s: re.sub(regex2, r"\1 \2", re.sub(regex1, "", s)), slist))

print(slist)
```

Result

```
['args', '-111111', '20 args', '20 - 20', '20-10', 'args deep']
```

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/qCqJr4)